# Pine Script enters the trades at the wrong time

Tags: pine-script

I'm working on different scripts at the moment and I've just started using the strategy function in pine script but I'm finding it multiple times giving me wrong inputs.

In this case I'm trying to enter when specific conditions apply and the prices then returns to the open of the previous candle, but only if it does this in the very next candle after the conditions are met.
For this I'm using the `strategy.enter` function and set the limit option to the open of the previous candle but sometimes, pinescript execute the order at the correct level, sometimes it does it at the close, and sometimes it does it at the correct level but multiple candles after the conditions were met.

[image: Entries at wrong candles and levels]

I can't seem to figure out why. I've tried different options and splitting up the codes but the results remain the same.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
lvl = 0.0
lvl := p2u ? p1uo : lvl[1]

bslvl = barssince(lvl != lvl[1])
bslvl1 = barssince(valuewhen(bar_index[1], lvl,0))
bslvl:= bslvl1[1] != 0 ? barssince(lvl) : bslvl

lentry = false
lentry  := p2u[1] ? lentry : na
lentry := lentry == p2u ? na : lentry
bslentry = barssince(lentry)
lentry := bslentry[1] < bslvl ? na : lentry



plot(lvl, color = #000000)


if lentry
    strategy.order("Long Entry", long = true, limit = lvl)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
...
if lentry
    strategy.order("Long Entry", long = true, limit = lvl)
else
    strategy.cancell("Long Entry")
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps with the entry on the wrong candles but the entry levels are still wrong for some reason. In some candles it enters at the right level but on some it enters at the close of the candle that crosses the level. It seems completely random. Any idea how to solve that problem?

Comment: The execution price can be equal or less then `lvl` for limit buy. If you don't see the execution prices doesn't respect this rule, it is ok.

Comment: I see. That's what I was thinking was the problem. Is there any way that you can think of that I could code it so to make it enter always exactly on `lvl`?

Comment: If you have the example when buy limit order has execution price above limit price, I'd like to look in it.

Comment: It never buys above limit price or sells below limit price but the entry at these more favorable levels mean that I cannot run more conservative strategy tests. I'd like it, if possible, to enter exactly at `lvl` price, like if I would place a market order manually at that price. Is that possible with pine script?

Comment: If you will place market orders and will use `process_orders_on_close=true` parameter for `strategy` declaration you will have execution prices exactly at close price of the bar. There is no option for now to force execute limit orders exactly specified price.